# Getting current image from scrollable list of images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have list of scrollable images ([example](https://denoutdoors.com/collections/aframe-house-plans/products/small-a-frame-house-with-loft?variant=39264937803840)) and I try to find out which is the current image that is shown of the screen.

The idea is to focus the current image thumbnail. Here is my code (I'm using Smarty TE):

```html
{if $images}
<div class="galleryHolder left">
    <div class="thumbsHolder left">
        <div class="pos-sticky">
            {section name=i loop=$images}
            <a href="/files/{$images[i].file}" data-fancybox="gallery" class="thumb">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="/files/webp/tntn/{$images[i].file_webp} 1x" type="image/webp">
                    <source srcset="/files/tntn/{$images[i].file} 1x" type="image/jpeg">
                    <img class="thumbImg" src="/files/tntn/{$images[i].file}" alt="{if $images[i].name}{$images[i].name}{else}{$row.name}{/if}">
                </picture>
            </a>
            {/section}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imagesHolder right">
        {section name=i loop=$images}
        <a href="/files/{$images[i].file}" data-fancybox="gallery" class="full">
            <picture>
                <source srcset="/files/webp/{$images[i].file_webp} 1x" type="image/webp">
                <source srcset="/files/{$images[i].file} 1x" type="image/jpeg">
                <img class="fullImg" src="/files/{$images[i].file}" alt="{if $images[i].name}{$images[i].name}{else}{$row.name}{/if}">
            </picture>
        </a>
        {/section}
    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put an intersectionObserver on each image then you will be notified when it comes into and goes out of the viewport.

In the callback function you can then set a class on the thumbnail to highlight it or not respectively.

Let me know if you want more help with the code.